# First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses, null]

Tags: apex, batch

I'm writing a batch job to send an email to a lead owner's manager.

```
global class LeadNotModified implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String eml = '123@gmail.com';
        String query = 'select LastModifiedDate, firstname from Lead where email = :eml';        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> scope) {
        List<Lead> lList = new List<Lead>();

        List<Lead> leadOwner = [select OwnerId from Lead WHERE Owner.Type IN ('User')];

        List<Id> leadOwnerId = new List<Id>();
        for(Lead lo : LeadOwner){
            leadOwnerId.add(lo.OwnerId);
        }  


        List<User> mgr = [select Manager.email FROM User where Id in :leadOwnerId];

        list<string> mgremails = new list<string>();
        for(User u : mgr){
            mgremails.add(u.manager.email);
        }


                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                mail.setSenderDisplayName('sfdc');
                mail.setToAddresses(mgremails);
                mail.setSubject('Hello There!');
                mail.setPlainTextBody('Lead not modified: ');

                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail});  
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

> First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses,
>   null]

Comment: Are you doing this in separate methods inside a batch? Can you include the entire batch class if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

If you want to get all manager emails for `Lead` records owned by a `User`, you can be much more efficient with query rows. You can do what is called a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join) in place of your first query, and these rows will not count against your governor consumption. Here's a more efficient structure:

```
List<String> managerEmails = new List<String>();
for (User owner : [
    SELECT Manager.Email FROM User WHERE Manager.Email != null AND Id IN (
        SELECT OwnerId FROM Lead
        // this is a Left Inner Join
        // these rows don't count against you
    )
]) managerEmails.add(owner.Manager.Email);
```

---

**Original**

One thing you need to make sure of is that `Manager.Email` is not null. Right now you assume that it has a value, but that is not necessarily the case. One way to ensure that it is would be to add a filter to your `WHERE` clause:

```
List<String> managerEmails = new List<String>();
for(User record : [
    SELECT Manager.Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :collection AND Manager.Email != null
]) managerEmails.add(record.Manager.Email);
```

Or if you are more comfortable with it, you could use post-processing:

```
List<String> managerEmails = new List<String>();
for(User record : [
    SELECT Manager.Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :collection
]){
    if (record.Manager.Email != null)
    {
        managerEmails.add(record.Manager.Email);
    }
}
```

One aspect to either solution is that you might get an empty list. You need to consider what behavior to execute in such a situation. Send to some fallback email? Don't send the email at all? Whatever you decide will affect how you proceed with your code modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make sure that you are not passing 'null' values like this:

```
list<string> mgremails = new list<string>();
    for(User u : mgr){
      if(u.manager.eamil != null)
        mgremails.add(u.manager.email);
    }
```